# Using Gamepad instead of Left and Right Arrows

Tags: unity-game-engine

This [arkanoid tutorial](http://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-arkanoid-game) they use this code to control the paddle:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
...
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
...
```

how to change it so the player can control it with a xbox360 controller or similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do to edit -> project settings -> input manager* then it will let you edit the buttons, so add some new buttons. Use GetButton instead of GetKey so it will allow for you to add xBox buttons, then in the input manager you should be able to start assigning gamepad buttons instead of keys to those buttons you created. If you're wondering what's what on an xbox controller here's a diagram.

http://wiki.unity3d.com/images/a/a7/X360Controller2.png

Sorry if something is wrong, it's late and I'm tired, but this should work!

*It may not be named exactly that I didn't check.